# how to loop few dos commands in C#

Tags: c#, loops

```
mp.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\Naag\\execute.bat";
mp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
mp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
mp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
mp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
for (i = StartSerialNo; i<EndSerialNo;i++)
{
    iCnt++;
    mp.StartInfo.Arguments = sFileName+StartSerialNo.ToString()+ " " + smyName;
    mp.Start();
    mp.WaitForExit();
}
```

Arguments of execute.bat is filename4567 myname. Now Execute.bat will create 4 .out files.

Since i want to loop it 10 time i should have got 40 .out file. But only 4 .out files i got.

Which indicates that loop was done only once. So what went wrong?

How to loop dos commands in C#?

Comment: Maybe execute.bat just overwrites those 4 files again and again?

Comment: The **StartSerialNo** is the same, maybe you want use **i**?

Comment: And where does DOS come into the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loop is using the same filename all the time meaning that it is just overwriting the files, you need to vary it.  Rather than using

```
sFileName+StartSerialNo.ToString()+ " " + smyName;
```

as the name you need to use the loop counter `i`:

```
sFileName + i + " " + smyName;
```

resulting in:

```
mp.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\Naag\\execute.bat";
mp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
mp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
mp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
mp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
for (i = StartSerialNo; i<EndSerialNo;i++)
{
    iCnt++;
    mp.StartInfo.Arguments = sFileName + i + " " + smyName;
    mp.Start();
    mp.WaitForExit();
}
```

putting a break point in your loop on the line where it creates the files would have shown you this (and that the loop was actually being executed 10 times)

Comment: hoooooooooooooooooooo!, Yes. Very bad developer. Wasted an hour for this. 
Any ways thanks a lot. :))

Comment: @Naag_Algates, I would treat this a lesson in self solving.  you should have been able to step though this loop in the debugger and inspect the values of the filenames and verify that the loop was being called 10 times and that you were overwriting the same file.  This would have taken you 5 minutes to solve.

Comment: But i want to run this exe in RDP. The same bat file is not accessible in local machine. That was the reason. So i have to build it n chk the  .out file rather than debugging it. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments sent to the process are the same on every loop, so the .bat is probably creating the same files every time.

My guess (and it's just a guess) is that you mean:

```
mp.StartInfo.Arguments = sFileName+i.ToString()+ " " + smyName;
```

Comment: Yes. Actually i should have added StartSerialNo++. Or i should have changed sFileName+StartSerialNo.ToString() to sFileName+i.ToString().
So thanks a lot! :))

Comment: dont need the .ToString after i its intelligent enough to decide its that anyway

Answer (score 1):

I Guess, because you haven't shared your .bat code that the .bat is not creating the output correctly and overwriting the same 4 files.